# How does the wait() call get invoked with notify in this code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, semaphore, condition-variable

I have a c++ code as follows that uses `condition-variable` for synchronization.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <condition_variable>

int n = 4;
enum class Turn { FOO, BAR };
Turn turn = Turn::FOO;

std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable cv;

void foo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);

        // wait for signal from bar & turn == FOO
        cv.wait(lock, [] {return turn == Turn::FOO; });

        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;

        // unlock & signal bar
        lock.unlock();
        turn = Turn::BAR;
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void bar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);

        // wait for signal from foo & turn == BAR
        cv.wait(lock, [] {return turn == Turn::BAR; });

        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;

        // unlock &  signal foo
        lock.unlock();
        turn = Turn::FOO;
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread thread_1(foo);
    std::thread thread_2(bar);
    thread_2.join();
    thread_1.join();
    
    return 0; 
}
```

The output observed:

[image: Output]

**Question:**

How would the `cv.wait(lock, [] {return turn == Turn::FOO; });` inside the `foo()` get triggered in the beginning?

From what I read, the `wait()` call with the predicate would be equivalent to:`while (!pred()) { wait(lock); }`. The predicate is true at the beginning (the initial value of `turn` is `Turn::FOO`), but how would the wait call get a notify? Regarding `wait()`, I see this:

*Atomically unlocks lock, blocks the current executing thread, and adds it to the list of threads waiting on *this. The thread will be unblocked when notify_all() or notify_one() is executed. It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is reacquired and wait exits.*

But I don't see the other thread's (the one running `bar()`)  to have it's `notify_one()` executed since `turn` is still `FOO`.

Comment: Where is this code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would the cv.wait inside the `foo()` get triggered in the beginning?

It would be triggered by the predicate evaluating to `true`. The equivalent loop:

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

would not call `wait()` even once (the first time that line of code is visited, anyway).

Comment: If that were the case, shouldn't the program print "foo bar foo bar ..." n times even after removing both the `cv.notify_one()` calls from both functions?

Comment: @skurup No, because one of the functions _does_ go into waiting at some point, and you need to notify it. Unless your scheduling is super-lucky ins witching from foo to bar and back so that they only ever hit the wait line when it's their turn.

Comment: Yeah, got it now. `cv.wait(lock, [] {return turn == Turn::FOO; });` should be read as *Wait for signal from bar() if turn != FOO* and `cv.wait(lock, [] {return turn == Turn::BAR; });` should be read as *wait for signal from foo() if turn != BAR*.

Comment: @skurup: Well, if this answers your question - please accept by clicking the checkmark.